# How to fix the expected a identifier

Tags: javascript

I'm learning JavaScript using the Code Academy website and whenever I try an `if` / `else` program it always comes up with `expected a identifier`. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. My program looks like this:

```
 confirm("Are you ready?")
    var age = prompt("What's your age?")
    if (age <= 18)
    console.log{"You are allowed to play but I take no responsibily";
    }
    else 
    {
    console.log ;"Have fun playing"
    }
```

Comment: did you paste your code in here? Is this letter-for-letter character for character what you were trying to run?

Answer (score 4):

To call the `console.log` function, you will need (round) parenthesis around its argument(s). Also you were missing the opening brace after the if-condition:

```
confirm("Are you ready?")
var age = prompt("What's your age?");
if (age <= 18) {
    console.log( "You are allowed to play but I take no responsibily" );
} else {
    console.log( "Have fun playing" );
}
```

Btw, you can omit the braces if there is only a single statement in the body of an `if`, `else`, `for`, etc. However, it's important to use proper indentation then:

```
confirm("Are you ready?")
var age = prompt("What's your age?")
if (age <= 18)
    console.log( "You are allowed to play but I take no responsibily" );
else
    console.log( "Have fun playing" );
```

Also notice that `prompt()` is returning a string, which you might want to [parse into a number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) before comparing it against 18:

```
 var age = parseInt( prompt("What's your age?"), 10);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if(confirm("Are you ready?"))
{
    var age = prompt("What's your age?");
    if (age <= 18)
    {
        console.log("You are allowed to play but I take no responsibily");
    }
    else 
    {
        console.log("Have fun playing");
    }
}
```

You need to use proper syntax. console.log for example is `console.log("text")`

Comment: Why that completely useless and confusing block?

Comment: @Bergi: Because I believe the intention was `if (confirm(...))`; otherwise the `confirm` itself is useless and should be `alert` (since there is no difference in consequences between the two buttons).

Comment: yes exactly. updated. i was going to suggest running it as a condition

Comment: @Bergi: Another possibility would be `while (!confirm(...));`, which is not useless, just annoying. (In that case, though, the block *is* useless and confusing.)

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to have a semi colon after each statement

```
confirm("Are you ready?")
var age = prompt("What's your age?")
```

needs to read

```
confirm("Are you ready?");
var age = prompt("What's your age?");
```

Comment: Even though I agree, leaving out semicolons is not an error in JS, just bad style.

Comment: oh, thanks @Amadan!  I was going to mention the braces but that was well covered.  :)